# hosting Asp.net Core developed in Windows 10 with visual studio 2017 in Docker run in Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I want To develop An Asp.net core Project and hosting it on Docker That exist in  Ubuntu server 16.04 i searching  for how to communicate between Visual studio that installed in Windows 10 and docker installed in Ubuntu server and  run project from windows if it applicable or not

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete answer, I'm learning this myself.

So far I have the followed the following pages and I have an Ubuntu server hosted on Azire running dotnet core 2.1, docker-ce and nginx
It can host test docker containers with aspnetcore apps inside them.

When I'm finished, I'll finish this answer:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1227574/Hosting-ASP-NET-Core-in-Linux

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

Right now I'm trying to figure out how Visual Studio 2017 connects to a server and publishes your project, runs and connects a debug channel.
It's something to do with `docker-compose`?